# SQL Case When Datepart

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having difficulty with SQL case when with datepart. Keep getting 
**"Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4. Incorrect syntax near '='".**

Really need help to solve this issue :(

```
Update <Table name>
Set Shiftcode = 
Case indttime
When datepart(hour,indttime) = 7 then 'ShiftM'
When datepart(hour,indttime) = 9 then 'Shift2'
Where (shiftcode = 'Shifwn' or shiftcode = 'shifwm') 
and (shiftdate > '2019-01-10 00:00:00:000' and shiftdate < '2019-02-11 00:00:00:000')
and staffno in (
Select distinct staffno
from <Table name>
where (shiftcode = 'Shifwn' or shiftcode = 'shiftwm')
and (shifdate > '2019-01-10 00:00:00:000' and shiftdate < '2019-02-11 00:00:00:000'));
```

Is there anything wrong with this code?

Comment: There is so much wrong with the code it is hard to begin.  Sample data, desired results, a database tag, and an explanation of what you want to do would all help.  Just for the record, `datepart()` is used correctly.

Comment: The `case` expression has no `end`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missed `end` of case expression

```
Update <Table name>
Set Shiftcode = 
Case When datepart(hour,indttime) = 7 then 'ShiftM'
When datepart(hour,indttime) = 9 then 'Shift2'
else null end
Where (shiftcode = 'Shifwn' or shiftcode = 'shifwm') 
and (shiftdate > '2019-01-10 00:00:00:000' and shiftdate < '2019-02-11 00:00:00:000')
and staffno in (
Select distinct staffno
from <Table name>
where (shiftcode = 'Shifwn' or shiftcode = 'shiftwm')
and (shifdate > '2019-01-10 00:00:00:000' and shiftdate < '2019-02-11 00:00:00:000'));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But i am still getting "Incorrect syntax near '='"

Comment: @AdrianHCY can you plz check again

Comment: Cool, it's working correctly now. Where did it go wrong?

Comment: @AdrianHCY case expression was a little bit wrong btw if it helps mark it as accepted answer

Comment: I see, just realise the case expression. Thank you so much for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a mess.  I suspect you want:

```
update <Table name>
    set Shiftcode = (case when datepart(hour, indttime) = 7 then 'ShiftM'
                          when datepart(hour, indttime) = 9 then 'Shift2'
                     end)
Where shiftcode in ('Shifwn', 'shifwm') and
      datepart(hour, indttime) in (7, 9) and
      shiftdate > '2019-01-10' and shiftdate < '2019-02-11';
```

This charges the shift names for the two shifts mentioned in the `where`, on the specified dates when they begin at the specified times.

Comment: Thank you so much, yes that is what I want. Sorry for the mess up code, I wasn't in this field from the beginning, my company just suddenly dump this on me and I learn it last week from searching through the web.

Comment: is there possibility I can run the code with between instead of  =?

Comment: @AdrianHCY . . . Yes, but that is not how you phrased your query.

Comment: I see, thanks for the help. Really need it and i learn something new here too

Answer (score 0):

Without formatting, it is hard to quickly detect if you are missing keywords like END. Always format your code and indent logical blocks (regardless of the language).

```
Update <Table name>
Set Shiftcode =
     Case /*indttime this should not be here*/
        When datepart(hour,indttime) = 7 then 'ShiftM'
        When datepart(hour,indttime) = 9 then 'Shift2'
    end /*end was missing here*/
Where /*(
        shiftcode = 'Shifwn'
    or  shiftcode = 'shifwm'
) This can be replaced with IN */
shiftcode IN ('Shifwn','shifwm')
and shiftdate > '2019-01-10 00:00:00:000'
and shiftdate < '2019-02-11 00:00:00:000'
and staffno in (
    Select distinct staffno
    from <Table name>
    where /*(
            shiftcode = 'Shifwn'
        or  shiftcode = 'shiftwm'
    ) This can be replaced with IN */
    shiftcode IN ('Shifwn','shiftwm')
    and shifdate > '2019-01-10 00:00:00:000'
    and shiftdate < '2019-02-11 00:00:00:000'
);
```

FYI, the shiftcodes don't match between the WHERE and the sub-select.

Comment: Kind of my first time handling SQL and I never had knowledge in coding until last week.

Comment: I guess the logic i am trying to use here is, for any shiftcode = "shifwn" and "shiftwm" from date range, need to be change to shiftm or shift2